# No puedo hacer un single select con Switch o RadioListTile Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, ios, dart

estoy intentando de realizar un listado de variantes o extras para una app de delivery, especificamente para el módulo de restaurantes, el problema que tengo es al utilizar un RadioListTile, todos los datos los estoy extrayendo de un API que es mi admin Panel en Laravel mi unico problema es que no puedo lograr que el usuario pueda seleccionar sólo una opción dependiendo del grupo al que pertenece el producto `

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SwitchListTile.adaptive(
      activeColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
     // checkColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      value: widget.extra.checked,
      onChanged:(value) {
        setState(() {
          //widget.extra.checked = value;
          widget.extra.checked = !widget.extra.checked;
          widget.onChanged();
          Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 200),(){
            Navigator.pop(context);
          });
          widget.onSelectedExtra;

        });
      },
      title:  Text(
        widget.extra?.name,
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3.merge(TextStyle(
            color: Theme.of(context).shadowColor,
            fontSize: 16
        )),
        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
      ),
      subtitle: widget.extra.price == 'null' || widget.extra.price == null || widget.extra.price == '0' || widget.extra.price == 0
          ? Helper.getPrice(0, context, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4.merge(TextStyle(
          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor
      )),)
          :Helper.getPrice(widget.extra.price, context, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4.merge(TextStyle(
          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor
      )),),
    );
  }
}
```

`En esta sección estoy llamando a un solo producto para listarlo posteriormente en esta otra sección`

```
if (_con.product.extraGroups == null)
                            CircularLoadingWidget(height: 100)
                          else
                            ListView.separated(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                              controller: ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 600),
                              itemBuilder: (context, extraGroupIndex) {
                                var extraGroup = _con.product.extraGroups.elementAt(extraGroupIndex);
                                return Wrap(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    ListTile(
                                      dense: true,
                                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                                      leading: Icon(
                                          Icons.add_circle_outline,
                                          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor
                                      ),
                                      title: Text(
                                        extraGroup?.name ?? '',
                                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1.merge(TextStyle(
                                            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                            fontSize: 16
                                        )),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  
                                    Container(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      ),
                                      child: ListTile(
                                        title:Text('Seleccione su ${extraGroup.name}',
                                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.merge(TextStyle(
                                              color: Theme.of(context).shadowColor,
                                              //fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                              fontSize: 13
                                          )),
                                        ),
                                       
                                        trailing: FlatButton(
                                          color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.4),
                                          shape:RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)
                                          ),
                                          onPressed:(){
                                            showModalBottomSheet(
                                                isScrollControlled: true,
                                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(30),topRight: Radius.circular(30))
                                                ),
                                                context: context,
                                                builder: (context){
                                                  return Wrap(
                                                    children: [
                                                      Padding(
                                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                        child: SizedBox(
                                                          child: ListView.separated(
                                                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                                            itemBuilder: (context, extraIndex) {
                                                              return ExtraItemWidget(
                                                                extra: _con.product.extras.where((extra) => extra.extraGroupId == extraGroup.id && extra.multiple_selection == true ).elementAt(extraIndex),
                                                                onChanged: _con.calculateTotal,
                                                              );
                                                            },
                                                            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                                                              return SizedBox(height: 0);
                                                            },
                                                            itemCount: _con.product.extras.where((extra) => extra.extraGroupId == extraGroup.id && extra.multiple_selection == true).length,
                                                            primary: false,
                                                            shrinkWrap: true,
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                      Padding(
                                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                        child: ListView.builder(
                                                          itemBuilder: (context, extraIndex) {
                                                        
                                                            return ExtraSingleItemWidget(
                                                              extra: _con.product.extras.where((extra) => extra.extraGroupId == extraGroup.id && extra.multiple_selection == false).elementAt(extraIndex),
                                                              onChanged: _con.calculateTotal,
                                                              onSelectedExtra: _con.SelectedExtra,
                                                            );
                                                     

                                                          },
                                                      
                                                          itemCount: _con.product.extras.where((extra) => extra.extraGroupId == extraGroup.id && extra.multiple_selection == false).length,
                                                          primary: false,
                                                          shrinkWrap: true,
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ],
                                                  );
                                                });
                                          },
                                          child: Wrap(
                                            children: [
                                              Text(
                                                'Seleccionar',
                                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button.merge(TextStyle(
                                                    color: Theme.of(context).shadowColor
                                                )),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                );
                              },
                              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return Divider(thickness:1.5,height: 20);
                              },
                              itemCount: _con.product.extraGroups.length,
                              primary: false,
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                            ),
```

`
Lo estoy llamando como ExtraSingleItemWidget una vez seleccionado el extra que pertenece a un producto en especifico este se añade automaticamente al precio base que aparece en un botón de añadir al carrito, lo que no se logra es que seleccione solo uno a la vez indistintamente de los grupos de extra a los que pertenece cada extra, [introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzTGa.jpg)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En las capturas se ve como se está comportando incluso con un Switch, lo que no debería ser así en este caso se debe poder seleccionar sólo uno de esas dos opciones, lo mismo pasa con algunas de esas categorías de extras

Answer (score 0):

No se si sea esta tu respuesta que buscas.

En el SwitchListTile.adaptive tienes un campo obligatorio "value" que eso permite si está activado o no si tienes el mismo value para todos entonces cuando selecciones uno se te marcara los demás por que todos tienen el mismo "value"

Ejemplo con el mismo value:

```
 class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool _lights = false;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
      Column(
      children: [

      SwitchListTile(
      title: const Text('Lights'),
      value: _lights,
      onChanged: (bool value) {
        setState(() {
          _lights = value;
        });
      },
      secondary: const Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
    ),
    
    SwitchListTile(
      title: const Text('Lights'),
      value: _lights,
      onChanged: (bool value) {
        setState(() {
          _lights = value;
        });
      },
      secondary: const Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
    ),
      ]);
  }
}
```

Ejemplo si tienes indepediente los values:

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool _lights = false;
    bool _lightstc = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
      Column(
      children: [

      SwitchListTile(
      title: const Text('Lights'),
      value: _lights,
      onChanged: (bool value) {
        setState(() {
          _lights = value;
        });
      },
      secondary: const Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
    ),
    
    SwitchListTile(
      title: const Text('Lights'),
      value: _lightstc,
      onChanged: (bool value) {
        setState(() {
          _lightstc = value;
        });
      },
      secondary: const Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
    ),
      ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu contribución pero si no estas seguro que es lo que se pregunta puedes primeramente preguntar para que el OP aclare lo que necesita y posteriormente puedes responder, revisar [answer] saludos